# styles.css not found 404 after executing setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: 404, static-content, static-content-deploy, styles, not-found

I'm trying to setup the project locally and after executing `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f es_ES` only sass directory is showing up but no css directory.
As you can see it is trying to request inside css directory but I don't have it after executing: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f es_ES`

This is how the page looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check the apache rewrite module is enabled.
2. Run all these commands.

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f es_ES
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on you **local root** to load style.css

```
ln -s pub/static static
```